# Parsec: Parsing expression between slashes

Tags: parsing, haskell, expression-trees, parsec, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse simple expressions between slashes. Example: `/ 1+2*3 /` should evaluate to `7`.

I was trying this

```
module Test where

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Language (emptyDef)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator (between)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)

import qualified Text.Parsec.Expr as Ex
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as Tok

lexer :: Tok.TokenParser ()
lexer = Tok.makeTokenParser style
  where
    ops = ["+","*","-","/",";"]
    names = ["def","extern"]
    style = emptyDef {
               Tok.commentLine = "#"
             , Tok.reservedOpNames = ops
             , Tok.reservedNames = names
             }

integer :: Parser Int
integer = fromIntegral <$> Tok.integer lexer

parens :: Parser a -> Parser a
parens = Tok.parens lexer

braces :: Parser a -> Parser a
braces = Tok.braces lexer

slashes :: Parser a -> Parser a
slashes = between (reserved "/") (reserved "/")

reserved :: String -> Parser ()
reserved = Tok.reserved lexer

reservedOp :: String -> Parser ()
reservedOp = Tok.reservedOp lexer

binary s f assoc = Ex.Infix (reservedOp s >> return f) assoc
table = [[binary "*" (*) Ex.AssocLeft,
          binary "/" div Ex.AssocLeft]
        ,[binary "+" (+) Ex.AssocLeft,
          binary "-" (-) Ex.AssocLeft]]

factor :: Parser Int
factor = try integer
      <|> parens expr

expr :: Parser Int
expr = Ex.buildExpressionParser table factor

programInSlashes :: Parser Int
programInSlashes = slashes expr

programInBraces :: Parser Int
programInBraces = braces expr
```

which works okay for `programInBraces`:

```
*Test> parse programInBraces "" "{ 1+2*3/4 }"
Right 2
```

however, `programInSlashes` does fail:

```
*Test> parse programInSlashes "" "/ 1+2*3/4 /"
Left (line 1, column 12):
unexpected end of input
expecting end of "/", integer or "("
```

Clearly the problem is that `/` is both an operator and the delimiter for the program itself. But as the language isn't ambiguous we should be able to parse that, no?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`Text.Parsec.Expr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html) to parse the interior expression; then you can embed backtracking for the `/` case, for example:

```
Infix (try $ do { reserved "/"; notFollowedBy eof; return div }) AssocLeft
```

You can also parse the exterior language and the interior expression in separate passes. I’ve done this in a compiler for a language with custom operators: first parse the program without touching infix expressions, then run another pass to parse infix expressions according to the operators in scope.

Comment: Sorry, only got to trying this out now. I can't get it to work unfortunately, still says `parse programInSlashes "" "/ 1+2*3/4 /"
Left (line 1, column 10):
unexpected '4'
expecting end of "/"`